# Warum verwendet "beginnen" "haben" als Hilfsverb in Perfekt?

Tags: verb, perfect-tense

Meiner ehemaligen Deutschlehrerin (und auch [anderen](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/german/writingh/2workexperiencerev1.shtml) [Quellen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_verbs#Perfect_infinitives)) zufolge wird *sein* als Hilfsverb in Perfekt genutzt, wenn das Verb intransitiv ist und auf eine Zustandsänderung (einschließlich Bewegung) hinweist, z. B. *haben gesehen* aber *sind gefahren*. Es gibt allerdings ein Paar Wörter, die *haben* nutzen, obwohl sie mir Zustandsänderungen zu sein scheinen, zum Beispiel:

> *Im Cannes hat das Filmfestival begonnen*
>
> *Das Konzert hat angefangen*
>
> *Die Tulpe hat geblüht*

In allen diesen Fallen sind die Verben intransitiv und weisen auf einen Übergang hin—von nicht angefangen bis begonnen, von nicht geblüht bis geblüht. Ist die Regel falsch oder (wahrscheinlicher) interpretierte ich es falsch?

---

English version:

According to my middle school German teacher (and also some [other](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/german/writingh/2workexperiencerev1.shtml) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_verbs#Perfect_infinitives)) *sein* as an auxiliary verb in Perfekt is used when the verb is intransitive and indicates a change in state (including a movement), e.g. *haben gesehen* but *sind gefahren*. However, there are a few words that take *haben* but to me are clearly changes of state, for example:

> *Im Cannes hat das Filmfestival begonnen*
>
> *Das Konzert hat angefangen*
>
> *Die Tulpe hat geblüht*

In all those cases the verbs are intransitive and show a transition—from not started to started, from un-blossomed to blossomed. Is the rule incorrect or (more likely) am I interpreting the *change of state* incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*anfangen*, *beginnen* und *aufhören* gehören zu den in Grammatiken üblicherweise genannten Ausnahmen der von dir zitierten generellen Regel, die oft stimmt, aber oft auch eben nicht. Du solltest diese Regel eher als Anhaltspunkt anstatt als unumstößliches Gesetz betrachten. Solche Ausnahmen muss man sich einfach merken, und es gibt auch noch mehr davon, auch solche Verben, bei denen *sowohl* "sein" als auch "haben" verwendet werden können, je nachdem, was ausgedrückt werden soll. Ein typisches Beispiel:

> Das Wasser in der Regentonne ist gefroren.

vs.

> Gestern morgen hat es mich gefroren, es hatte minus 10 Grad.

oder auch viele Verben der Bewegung wie *schwimmen, joggen, fahren*. Auch bei denen stimmt deine Regel allerdings einigermaßen: Geht es um die *pure Aktivität*, nimmt man "haben", geht es um die *Ortsveränderung*, nimmt man "sein":

> Ich bin zweimal über den See geschwommen
>
> Ich bin nach Nürnberg gefahren

vs.

> Gestern habe ich endlich mal wieder gejoggt
>
> Der Unvallverursacher hat trotz 2.0 Promille Alkohol den Wagen gefahren

Ausserdem gibt es noch regionale Unterschiede:

z.B. *liegen, stehen, sitzen* verwenden im Norden des deutschen Sprachraums eher "haben" für die Perfektbildung, je weiter man in den Süden kommt, wird eher "sein" verwendet. Hier ist damit ohne irgendeinen Bedeutungsunterschied beides richtig.

Zurück zu deiner Frage: *blühen* als Zustandsänderung zu betrachten, halte ich für grenzwertig.

> Das Maiglöckchen blüht im allgemeinen weiß

drückt z.B. keinerlei Zustandsänderung aus.

Nehmen wir stattdessen *aufblühen*, das definitiv die Zustandsänderung von "nicht blühend" nach "blühend" beschreibt, und schon haben wir wieder *sein* als Hilfsverb.

> Sabine ist während ihres Studiums richtiggehend aufgeblüht

Comment: Weil mich das interessiert: Hast Du Quellen für das wechselnde Hilfsverb bei *joggen*? Gilt es auch für ähnlich gebrauchtes *laufen*? Was ist bei transitiver Benutzung wie *den Hamburgmarathon gelaufen/gejoggt*?
Falls Du das passender findest, kann ich auch eine Frage dazu stellen.

Comment: @CarstenS Duden: *Viele Bewegungsverben können das Perfekt sowohl mit haben als auch mit sein bilden, also z. B. ich habe geschwommen – ich bin geschwommen, sie hat gejoggt – sie ist gejoggt. Werden diese Verben allerdings mit einer Richtungs- oder Ortsangabe verbunden, ist nur die Perfektbildung mit sein möglich: Sie ist gestern nach Mannheim gefahren. Wir sind ein bisschen durch die Innenstadt gebummelt.
Generell nimmt bei den Bewegungsverben die Perfektbildung mit sein zu, also eher Wir sind den ganzen Tag geklettert oder Sie ist schon viele Bahnen geschwommen.*

Comment: @CarstenS ... und *ich **habe** gelaufen* funktioniert (zumindestens für mich) irgendwie nicht. Selbst bei transitiver Verwendung mit Akkusativobjekt nimmt man hier i.A. automatisch "sein", obwohl alle Kriterien für "haben" da wären : *...wir sind den Schwarzwald-Höhenweg gelaufen*

Comment: Danke fürs Raussuchen! Mein Problem bei dieser Frage ist, dass ich nicht mehr sagen kann, was ich vor, ichsagmal, dreißig Jahren natürlich gesagt hätte. Sprache kann merkwürdig sein.